# Is there any way to get if react final form has touched status outside of form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I use react final form in another component, say dialog div and I want to check was this form changed before close this dialog div (to show a message like 'You have unsaved changes').

Here is an example, I have no idea how to call onChange in a form on final-form changes - in  tag it will not work in case I use some custom input and in validate method it looks too dirty.

```
class Dialog extends Component {
    ...
    onFormChange = () => this.setState({isFormChanged: true})
    close() {
        if (this.isFormChanged){
            this.showDialog()
        } else {
            //close dialog
        }
    }
    render(){
        return <div>
            <MyForm onChange={this.onFormChange} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

and a form

```
function MyForm({ saveData, onChange, ...props }) {
    return <div>
        <Form
            onSubmit={saveData}}
            render={({
                handleSubmit,
            }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} onChange={() => onChange()}>
                    </form>
```

Comment: There is `pristine` in `FormRenderProps` which you can use to check if any field is dirty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking into `<FormSpy>` helper component and it's `onChange` prop: https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#formspyprops